# Jumps in signal/noise ratio on problematic VDSL connection

Tags: noise, transmission-line, modem

(I am not sure this question is on-topic here. It seemed off-topic in networking because the connection is not in a professionally managed environment. Perhaps super user would be a better fit? But then I'm curious about the DSLAM's role for which I hope to find expertise here. Feel free to comment or turf right away if you can.)

I have a vectored VDSL connection, ITU-T G.993.5, profile 17a, to my apartment which is located in the back wing of a large building. My Fritz box 7362 SL reports 268m to the DSLAM of which around 100m must be on the property. Usually the connection works well but occasionally there are phases where the connection quality is so bad that the modem disconnects, sometimes so often that the line is virtually unusable. Such an event happened yesterday. When I checked the connection properties I noticed that the signal/noise ratio is at times entirely stable but at other times varying, sometimes to the point that errors occur. That in itself is not so surprising: Cross-talk or interference from faulty devices close to the line may be present at times, but at other times not.

What I did find surprising though was that I can identify two phases of stable signals with entirely different noise/signal ratios, see the screenshot below (displaying reception levels, 4 bars is 24 hours). From the fact that during both phases the signal was very were stable I conclude that there was no significant noise in either phase — noise would have a random element and lead to fluctuations like in the first 6 bars. Which implies that the ratio difference does not come from a different noise level but from a different signal level — but the difference is 7 or 8 dB, that is, a power factor of 5 or 6.
[image]

**What can be the reason for such a large difference in sustained signal strength?**

It looks like a different line, but I think that's impossible; to my understanding I have a dedicated, hard-wired telephone line to the DSLAM. Is my understandig wrong? Alternatively, the DSLAM must have increased its output signal level. Do they do that?

For completeness I include the VDSL details and the frequency spectrum:

[image]

[image]

Comment: *the signal strength (or better: signal/noise ratio)* Which of the two?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The ratio, as can be seen in the diagram. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

> From the fact that during both phases the signal was very were stable I conclude that there was no significant noise in either phase — noise would have a random element and lead to fluctuations like in the first 6 bars.

If there was no significant noise, your SNR would have been near-infinite all the time. The fact that it's not, even on the "good" carriers, is due to noise being present.

Of course, you're right, noise fluctuates, but "noise power" is a property of the expectation of noise (the variance). You have constant variance with very fluctuating values!

> hich implies that the ratio difference does not come from a different noise level but from a different signal level — but the difference is 7 or 8 dB, that is, a power factor of 5 or 6.

Different power levels are less likely than different interference levels. Still might be the case, if your DSLAM needs to budget its transmit power across multiple users. But that's unlikely, because every subscriber line gets its own amplifier. Unless you forgot to tell us you're on a *vectoring* subscriber line, where the signals send down a bundle of cables are generated coordinatedly.

So, it's probably time-varying interference. Either from badly behaving electronic devices, or plainly DSL traffic for other users on nearby lines.

Anyway, 8 dB is not *that* much variation, honestly.

> It looks like a different line, but I think that's impossible; to my understanding I have a dedicated, hard-wired telephone line to the DSLAM. Is my understandig wrong?

Yep, DSL crosstalk is a very important topic.

> Alternatively, the DSLAM must have increased its output signal level. Do they do that?

They probably decrease it when the interference situation is good enough - no use spreading more interference to others, nor any use to spend power. Operating a phone network with millions of subscribers simply costs real money in terms of electricity, and every milliwatt you save per subscriber sums up nicely in your quarterly reports.

Comment: "G.Vector full" in the properties seems to indicate vectored, I assume? I honestly was not sure. OK, profile 17a and the download speed >50 MBit/s mean yes, it is a vectored connection. How does that change what the DSLAM can do?